# How to integrate mark message feature for read messages in Quickblox

Tags: objective-c, quickblox

I am using `Chatviewcontroller` of `Quickblox` to show chat detail. I want to mark the message to read if the message is read.

I see there is a method available in QMChatService.m class

```
- (void)chatDidReadMessageWithID:(NSString *)messageID
                    dialogID:(NSString *)dialogID
                    readerID:(NSUInteger)readerID{

------------
if ([self.multicastDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(chatService:didUpdateMessage:forDialogID:)]) {
            [self.multicastDelegate chatService:self didUpdateMessage:message forDialogID:dialogID];
        }
}
```

Here I see `chatService:didUpdateMessage:` a method called for another scenario too hence unable to identify how to mark the message.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved like this
QBChatMessage has three properties readIDs(array of the users who read the messages), deliveredIDs(array of the users to whom message is delivered), recipientID.

Below is full code in ChatViewController.m

-(void)collectionView:(QMChatCollectionView *)collectionView
      configureCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell 
          forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

QBChatMessage *message = [self.chatDataSource messageForIndexPath:indexPath];

```
if (message.senderID == [QBSession currentSession].currentUser.ID){

    NSString *imageName = @"sent.png";
    if((self.dialog.type == QBChatDialogTypePrivate) && [message.readIDs containsObject:@(message.recipientID)]) {
        imageName = @"read.png";
    }
    else if((self.dialog.type == QBChatDialogTypePrivate) && [message.deliveredIDs containsObject:@(message.recipientID)]) {
        imageName = @"received.png";
    }
    [chatCell markImageView].image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

}

Here markImageView is UIImagview property taken for the cell.